# How to add Hex font color to a JLabel?

Tags: java, colors, jlabel

I searched stackOverFlow for answers but I still coudn't find any (only for android. I use commandline). I want to add Hex color code as the font color.

I first used this but I need to add out from JDK given system/defined colors

```
g2l2.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
```

Something like this. But didn't work.

```
g2l2=new JLabel();
g2l2.setLocation(50,60);        
g2l2.setSize(150,30);        
g2l2.setText("Members");        
g2l2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#43B7BA"));        
g2l2.setFont(new Font("Calibri Light",Font.BOLD,15));        
g2cont.add(g2l2);    
g2l2.addMouseListener(this);
```

ERROR: Cannot find symbol Color.parseColor(String) in Location: class Color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Color myColor = Color.decode("#43B7BA");
```

This worked for me once.

Hope it helped you.

Regards.

By the way, you can try also using the "RGB" approach, there are many pages which can get the RGB values from an hex:

```
Color redColor = new Color(255,0,0)
```

Comment: You can also try with `Color myColor = new Color(0x43B7BA);`

Comment: Ok how to add myColor variable to the jlabel? Sorry for asking this silly question. Parden me as i'm a beginner. First time using java.awt.Color.

Comment: @Marcelo Tataje I used this: g2l2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(myColor)); it doesn't work:( Can you help?

Comment: @AshaneAlvis use `g2l2.setForeground(Color.parseColor(myColor))`

Comment: @BackSlash The compiler says cannot find symbol method parseColor. Do I have to import any packages?

Comment: @AshaneAlvis import `java.awt.Color`. And use `Color.decode` instead of `Color.parseColor`, as `parseColor` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older thread but I believe the OP's original issue was not including the correct import. He had the right answer already figured out.

```
import android.graphics.Color;
```

To parse HEX colors in Android you would simply do this... after the import:

```
Color.parseColor("#000000")//BLACK
```

Or as the OP already had it...after the import:

```
g2l2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#43B7BA"));
```